# Help identifying and getting datasheets for circuit board and LCD

Tags: pcb, identification, lcd, reverse-engineering

Overall goal: I have a 400 kg mini crane hanging scale that displays the weight on a LCD. I want to add Bluetooth to it so that, in addition to the LCD, the data goes to a phone app or computer. This particular brand is Cabela's but they don't have any info on it.

As I see it, I can either get the data from the load cell itself (a Truesun 400 kg s-beam cell) or intercept the output to the LCD.

To do the latter, I need to have the datasheet for either or both the circuit board and LCD, right? I've read through an [Instructable](https://www.instructables.com/Direct-Reading-of-LCD-Using-General-Purpose-IO/) about the process if you don't have the datasheet and I would like to avoid that if possible.
Numbers I can see on the board are:
sf916-v1.0
20180926,
B102941

[image]

[image]

There are no identifying marks on the LCD. Attaching pictures of the load cell and board.

As you can probably tell, I'm new to this, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It *might* have the same pin configuration as this one, since a lot of different displays use this config: https://cdn.sos.sk/productdata/7f/6b/5f682254/bc-1604a-bnheh-1.pdf

Comment: All in all, it is probably easier to attach an opamp to the S+/S- lines and do your own analogue to digital conversion

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Forgive the total noob, should I be looking for the datasheet for the loadcell then? I want to avoid buying a logic analyzer or oscilloscope if possible. That may be a stupid question so I will start researching pulling data from a load cell. Thank again!

Comment: no need, just measure the voltage across S+/S- for different weights with a simple voltmeter, and go from there